# LInq left join with multiple condition in on clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a join in SQL I need to write it in linq here is the `select` statment:

```
select * from products p
left join customer cust
on((cust.identifier = p.orgID or cust.identifier = p.personalno) and cust.identifier is not null);
```

How can I write this statement in linq?

Comment: Use `Where` instead of `Join`

Comment: i already read it many times ago there is nothing about condition in on clause there.. kasebrot...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- If you really want to do it with a `JOIN`, you could do it like this:

  ```
  from cust in customer
  join _p1 in products on cust.identifier equals _p1.orgID into _p1
  from p1 in _p1.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join _p2 in products on cust.identifier equals _p2.personalno into _p2
  from p2 in _p2.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where cust.identifier != null
  && (p1 != null || p2 != null)
  select new { Customer = cust, Product = p1 == null ? p2 : p1 }
  ```
- An easier solution without the `JOIN`keyword would be:

  ```
  from p in products
  from cust.Where(q => q.identifier != null && (p.orgID == q.identifier || p.personalno == q.identifier)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  where cust != null
  select new { Product = p, Customer = cust }
  ```
- To answer the question, that the headline suggests, do the following to do a join on multiple conditions, but be aware, that this only works for `AND` conditions and not for `OR` conditions:

  ```
  from t1 in Table1
  join t2 in Table2 on new { Criteria1 = t1.criteria1, Criteria2 = t1.criteria2 } equals new { Criteria1 = t2.criteria1, Criteria2 = t2.criteria2 }
  select new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 }
  ```

Comment: nice work +1, 2nd bulletin answer is very useful for my code, i was struggling by adding where condition for child table with left join, from your code i updated where condition in the join itself. I also referred this link                    http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/LEFT-OUTER-JOIN-with-ON-condition-or-WHERE-condition